# SQL Named Pipes across Site to Site VPN

Tags: vpn, sql-server-2008, sql, named-pipes

Running into SQL issues and I can find the exact problem already posted here on SF.

I have a SQL server running on a 192.168.16.x subnet on one side of a site to site VPN.  I have a workstation on a 172.16.100.x subnet on the other.

SQL Browser running on SQL server and computer browser running on DCs and all workstations on both sides.  Computer browser correctly shows all computers on both sides together.

I can ping and resolve all hostnames both directions, but when adding a SQL DSN, the SQL instance name does not populate the dropdown on the 100.x side, only on the 16.x side.  All traffic and ports are open on the vpn.

The software application I need to setup requires the SQL instance is broadcast and selectable.  It requires a DSN and basically needs to be able to be configured by selecting a SQL instance in the app as well.  You can not just type it in...it will not work.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about SQL instance discovery, but assuming this is based on broadcast then it would never cross the IP network borders (which explains the behaviour you're witnessing, if your software is in the 16.X side of the VPN).

If that's indeed the problem, a workaround (note I diddn't call it a solution) would be to set up some network address translation to redirect broadcast from network 16.X to the broadcast address of the network 100.X if your router allows it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had considered that and I am far from a SQL DBA, but it was my understanding that SQL Server uses udp/1434 for returning information on how to connect to a named instance. SQL Server uses tcp, not udp, for all actual communication between client and server.  all udp and tcp ports are open, so I thought this would be good enough.

Comment: unfortunately opening port is not enough.If the discovery is based on broadcast, there is not much chance to cross the network borders (expect with some ugly tricks). multicast based discovery or msdns would be the way to make it network agnostic.